# How do I get a TeckNet New Webcam Camera to work?

Tags: drivers, webcam

I recently bought [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Q3VECE) webcam. I stupidly assumed Ubuntu would automatically recognize it as it has done with everything else so far, can anyone help me to get it to work? At the moment, when I plug it in, nothing happens and doesn't appear to be recognized. Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My gosh, that is, most definitely the most stupid question I have ever asked in my life. The webcam works fine and was recognized, I just didn't realize! Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Look at "TeckNet webcam" - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8868745